# How to Call postgresql refrence cursor in php pdo

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ai.b_listen_php_mm_hst(
    IN i_qot_id double precision,
    IN i_start timestamp without time zone,
    IN i_end timestamp without time zone,
    IN i_order_by text,
    IN i_max_rows double precision,
    OUT o_recordset refcursor)
  RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    X_QOT_ID DOUBLE PRECISION;
BEGIN
    --PERFORM qf.logging$log_procedure('COMMIT'::unresolved_type, 'B_LISTEN_PHP_MM'::unresolved_type, 'HST'::unresolved_type, CONCAT_WS('', 'i_qot_id=', i_qot_id), ''::unresolved_type);
    X_QOT_ID := ai.b_listen_php_mm_get_qot_id(i_qot_id);

    OPEN o_recordset FOR execute 'SELECT dpr_id, dpr_qot_id, to_char( dpr_ts, ''DD.MM.YYYY'') dpr_ts, dpr_close, dpr_open, dpr_high, dpr_low, dpr_kasse, dpr_volume, dpr_close_bid, dpr_spl_bereinigt, dpr_open_interest, dpr_turnover  FROM
               ( SELECT rownum, dpr_id, dpr_qot_id,  dpr_ts, dpr_close, dpr_open, dpr_high, dpr_low, dpr_kasse, dpr_volume, dpr_close_bid, dpr_spl_bereinigt, dpr_open_interest, dpr_turnover
                  FROM dpr
                 WHERE dpr_qot_id = ' || X_QOT_ID || ' AND dpr_ts>=  nvl(''' || i_start || ''', sysdate-12000) and dpr_ts <= nvl(''' || i_end || ''', sysdate )
                 ORDER BY  ' || i_order_by || ')
                 WHERE rownum <= nvl(''' || i_max_rows || ''', 5000 )';

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION ai.b_listen_php_mm_hst(double precision, timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone, text, double precision)
  OWNER TO pgfine;
```

When I m calling this function using my php pdo like:

```
$aibcon->beginTransaction();
    // call the function
    $stmt = $aibcon->prepare("select * from ai.b_listen_php_mm_hst(:i_qot_id,to_date(:i_start, 'DD.MM.YYYY'),to_date(:i_end, 'DD.MM.YYYY'),:i_order_by,:i_max_rows)");
    $stmt->bindParam('i_qot_id', $i_qot_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam('i_start', $i_start, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('i_end', $i_end, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('i_order_by', $i_order_by, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('i_max_rows', $i_max_rows, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $cursors = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->closeCursor();
```

I am getting the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [o_recordset] => 
        )
)
```

But when running on pgsql window it is showing correct data:

```
select * from  ai.b_listen_php_mm_hst(2028115786,to_date('01.01.1970','DD.MM.YYYY'),to_date('19.08.2016','DD.MM.YYYY'),'dpr_ts DESC NULLS LAST',1);
fetch all in "<unnamed portal 16>";
```

Please help i am feeling so helpless on this

Comment: You'll need to run `fetch` in php too. F.ex. [like this](http://trentrichardson.com/2012/01/04/return-multiple-result-sets-with-php-and-postgresql-functions/).